# Protect AdWords Scripts

Tags: obfuscation, google-ads-api

My company is attempting to protect its scripts used in Google AdWords. We want to share them with clients and other agencies, but retain proprietary control. Which may be impossible, especially in AdWords.

One idea is to use Obfuscation, however some portions of the scripts cannot be obfuscated in order to work in adwords.

Another idea is to place the entire script in a Google drive doc use Google drive as a gateway. However, this makes the scripts buggy.

We could pull out the data, run the script outside of the Google AdWords interface and pull it back in, but we lose access to certain functionality of the Adwords interface.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is running script from an external file. If you store your script in Google Drive and give permission to only the user who authorizes script. So your clients cannot reach the codes. If you pre-authorize your script, it's should be fine like:

```
// UrlFetchApp.fetch();



function main() {
  var url = "http://example.com/asdf.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gokaan is not too far off.  I use a base loader script (sort of like a base class in code).  The base (AKA script runner) is in charge of loading scripts to run from a Google Drive document.  It works best if you have an MCC account because you give the base script permissions through your MCC login.  That way, your client can't get to the true scripts, only to the loader (which is worthless from an IP perspective).  And if they off you, you off them.

You can read more about it on Russ Savage's site, which is a great resource.

http://www.freeadwordsscripts.com/search/label/generic%20script%20runner

The only issue I have had is when you have many, many accounts trying to WRITE to a shared Google Drive document.  Depending on how you write your code, you may get overwrite issues b/c you cannot set the exact time a script runs (google only promises hourly).

Since then, Google now allows parallel scripts.  That is my next move - migrate the script runner to the MCC level, the script then iterates through the accounts it should apply the scripts to.  Much slicker but will take some reworking.

Good luck.